# Cause of my roof leaking? (Victorian house with photos)

Tags: leak, roof, roofing, leaking

I was putting some stuff in the loft of my Victorian house (UK) and found the roof was dripping wet on the inside and it is wet pretty much everywhere, not just in one area.

I have looked at the roof on both sides and don't see anything obvious.

I was looking for a slate that was out of place but couldn't see anything. Even if there was a dislodged slate that wouldn't explain why it's wet everywhere.

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Below are some photos from today but it was much worse a few days ago and there were small puddles on any of the plastic bags up there.

Front
[image]

Back
[image]

Inside loft
[image]

2
[image]

Inside loft video
[Video inside loft](https://photos.app.goo.gl/xjC5AQ5x8pgJkZaKA)

Comment: Depending on insulation and air movement, it could be condensation (if warm, moist air from inside the ouse is getting up and hitting the underside of a cold roof) - "pretty much everywhere" is my clue here - roof leaks don't tend to do that, but condensation does.

Comment: Is that the backside of the slate with all the beads of water on it? If it is I fully agree with Ecnerwal, place a glass of ice water in the room and if the glass starts dripping you have proved that there is a lot of moisture in your loft and ventilation is needed or a dehumidifier.

Comment: Yes it's the back side. See the video here https://photos.app.goo.gl/xjC5AQ5x8pgJkZaKA
Condensation was my first thought but 1 l have never seen it before (I don't go to the loft often but at least twice a year for 7 years) and 2. It is very wet.

Comment: I agree with the diagnosis.  Condensation is very wet.  :). It does look like condensation.  If you look twice a year you might not see it.  This will happen when it's cold outside and warm and humid inside.

Comment: @Ecnerwal you should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to identify where the leak is coming from, get a buddy and have him spray your roof with water using a hose while your in the loft looking for water.  Have him start from the low point of the roof and slowly work his way up.  Sine you don't sound like a roofer I'd say this is your easiest way to find the leak.

Don't forget to give me a thumbs up so I get credit for helping you.

Good luck